# Search files with multiple "dot" characters

Tags: linux, design-patterns, find, character

In Linux how do I use find and regular expressions or a similar way without writing a script to search for files with multiple "dots" but IGNORE extension.

For e.g search through the following files will only return the second file. In this example ".ext" is the extension.

```
testing1234hellothisisafile.ext
testing.1234.hello.this.is.a.file.ext
```

The solution should work with one or more dots in the file name (ignoring the extension dot). This should also work for any files i.e. with any file extension

Thanks in advance

Comment: Effectively you are looking for files that contain more than 3 dots, right?

Comment: more than a single dot. i.e. ignoring the extension dot there can only be one or more dots in the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to get the filenames with at least two additional dots in the name. This would do:

```
$ find -regex ".*\.+[^.]*\.+[^.]*\.+.*"
./testing.1234.hello.this.is.a.file.ext
./testing1234.hellothisisafile.ext
$ find -regex ".*\.+[^.]*\.+[^.]*\.+[^.]*\.+.*"
./testing.1234.hello.this.is.a.file.ext
```

The key dot detecting part is `\.+` (at least one dot), coupled with the separating anything (but a dot, but the previous part covers it already; a safety measure against greedy matching) `[^.]*`. Together they make the core part of the regex - we don't care what is before or after, just that somewhere there are three dots. Three since also the one from the current dir matters — if you'll be searching from elsewhere, remove one `\.+[^.]*` group:

```
$ find delme/ -regex ".*\.+[^.]*\.+[^.]*\.+[^.]*\.+.*"
delme/testing.1234.hello.this.is.a.file.ext
$ find delme/ -regex ".*\.+[^.]*\.+[^.]*\.+.*"
delme/testing.1234.hello.this.is.a.file.ext
```

In this case the result is the same, since the name contains a lot of dots, but the second regex is the correct one.

Comment: sorry i was vague. it should work with any number of dots ignoring the extension dot.

Comment: then just remove another group from my response (like already mentioned).

Comment: I created file named `index.php.txt` and ran the command `find . -regex ".*\.+[^.]*\.+.*"` but it wasn't able to locate the file. Did I understand correctly how to adapt this command to find files with two dots in the filename?

Comment: I got folders with only one DOT when I tried either of the REGEX expressions. So please use this accepted answer with extreme caution. If you plan on deleting files using this command then most likely you will delete something you did not intend to delete.

Comment: That's pretty much impossible unless you mistyped/mispasted something or have a bug in find or the shell, since the regex won't match unless the name has at least 3 dots somewhere in it.